# Redirection in Laravel 5 built in User Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

After successful login User redirected to this

`Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');`

But I would like to redirect User to this

`Route::get('home',['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@index']);`

How can I do that ??

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the AuthenticatesUsers trait?

Comment: I am using `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait. I am using Laravel 5 .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait, when the login succeed, there is a call to a method called `redirectPath()`. That method checks for the existence of the properties `redirectPath` and `redirectTo` in that order, so in your controller, you can define one of them.

So, in your auth controller, do one of these:

```
public $redirectPath = 'path/to/go';
```

or

```
public $redirectTo = 'path/to/go';
```

If you want to get the path using a function, such as `route()` for a named route or `action()` to get the route to a controller method, you can't use one of the previous properties because in PHP this is wrong:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public $redirectPath = route('name.of.the.route');
    ...
}
```

In such a case, you can always override the `redirectPath()` method:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        return route('name.of.the.route');
    }
    ...
}
```